# How to make delimited item in split_at (more_itertools) dynamic

Tags: python-3.x, list, split, delimiter, more-itertools

I am using **split_at** from **more_itertools**. The reason is that I have a list of 70k records in which *Record i*  *[Record 1, Record 2, ...Record n]* occurs. I need to split the list at these *Record i* occurences. How can i implement this in the following code?

Note tha *n* is unkown

```
Result = list(split_at(lst, lambda x: x == 'Record i'))
```

This is my input (subset)

```
[1] "Record 1"
[1] 1010286
[1] 7
[1] F
[1] "Record 2"
[1] 1000152
[1] 5
[1] M
```

This is my desired output (in a dataframe)

```
"Record 1", 1010286, 7, F 
"Record 2", 1000152, 5, M
```

Comment: Can you post some sample (input) input and expected output? Maybe it can be done without `more_itertools`, just by using standard library

Comment: Please, put your input/expected output to your question, not to comments section - and don't forget about correct formatting.

Comment: @JeroenSchuddebeurs, Does your input represent Dataframe column values?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, it represents a list

Comment: @JeroenSchuddebeurs, why don't post it appropriately as a list?

Comment: What if the input would be `[a,2,3,"Record 1",1010286,7,F,"Record 2",1000152,5,M]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, sorry for the confusion but the input is indeed a dataframe (I converted the second column into a list)

Comment: @JeroenSchuddebeurs, post the expected result for the input in my previous comment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I am not sure what you mean (sorry bit of a newby here)